# Approximating a measurable set by measurable rectangles

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Is the following claim correct? I couldn't find it in standard texts (say, Bogachev).

**Claim.** Let $(X=\prod_{i=1}^n X_i,\mathcal{A}=\otimes_{i=1}^n \mathcal{A}_i)$ be a product of measurable spaces $(X_i,\mathcal{A_i})$, and let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $\mathcal{A}$. For every $Y\in \mathcal{A}$ and every $\varepsilon>0$ there exist finitely many disjoint measurable rectangles $R_j\in \mathcal{A}$, i.e., sets of the form $R_j=\prod_{i=1}^n Y_i$ for $Y_i\in\mathcal{A}_i$, such that
$$\mu(Y\Delta \bigcup_j R_j)<\varepsilon,$$
where $\Delta$ denotes symmetric difference.

Below is a short sketch that, if valid, is quite standard I suppose. My knowledge in measure theory is extremely basic though, so if this is utterly wrong, I wouldn't be surprised.

**Idea.** Let
$\mathcal{M}$ denote the set of $Y\in\mathcal{A}$ for which the claim is true. Finite unions of disjoint measurable rectangles are by definition contained in $\mathcal{M}$, and they form an algebra. By the dominated convergence theorem, $\mathcal{M}$ is a monotone class. By the monotone class theorem, $\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks correct to me. Let $A$ dentote the algebra of finite disjoint unions of rectangles. You have proved that $\{\chi_S : S \in A\}$ is dense in $\{\chi_E : E \in \mathcal{A}\}$ in the $L^1(X, \mu)$ norm. The only hypotheses you really used are that $\sigma(A) = \mathcal{A}$ and $\mu(X) < \infty$.

Comment: Thanks! I just now realized that by allowing an approximation with countable unions of rectangles, the same argument yields $\mu(Y\Delta \bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}R_j)=0$. I find this quite surprising given that measurable sets can be quite complex (say, the rotation of a product of two fat cantor sets in the plane).

Comment: The previous comment is wrong... (couldn't edit it)